# Why is Franky's Strong Right a rollercoaster car?

Tags: one-piece

When watching episode 583, I noticed that Franky's Strong Right attack looked like a roller coaster car. Is this just a design choice or some hidden pun?

[image]

Comment: After thinking it over a bit I think it might actually be a pun right/ride with almost the same pronunciation, Strong ride.

Comment: Whoa, that's a pretty good pun. I totally agree. Nice catch there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Frankie article](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_Frankies/BF-37) on One Piece Wiki that is actually meant to be a **flame-shaped plate**.

> **Strong Right** (ストロング右（ライト） Sutorongu Raito?): A new version of the original Strong Right, Franky launches his much bigger right fist at his opponent akin to a rocket, with a chain to retract it. The fist also has flame-shaped plates on the sides with "STRONG" written on them that seem to be purely for aesthetic design. His fist also seems to have an electrical charge. This was first seen used against the attackers on Punk Hazard.

This indeed make much more sense than a rollercoaster car and is more fitting with Franky robot style.

Comment: Tbh, I hoped Dimitri was right, since I liked the pun on "Strong ride" vs "Strong right", but a flame makes sense too :(

Comment: @PeterRaeves Yeah, I liked the idea. All tough I will most likely always look at it as if it is a roller coaster cart ;)